# How to leverage Z3 SMT solver for ILP problems

Tags: z3, linear-programming, smt

*Problem*

I'm trying to use z3 to disprove reachability assertions on a Petri net.

So I declare N state variables v0,..v_n-1 which are positive integers, one for each place of a Petri net.

My main strategy given an atomic proposition P on states is the following :

- compute (with an exterior engine) any "easy" positive invariants as linear constraints on the variables, of the form alpha_0 * v_0 + ... = constant with only positive or zero alpha_i, then check_sat if any state reachable under these constraints satisfies P, if unsat conclude, else
- compute (externally to z3) generalized invariants, where the alpha_i can be negative as well and check_sat, conclude if unsat, else
- add one positive variable t_i per transition of the system, and assert the Petri net state equation, that any reachable state has a Parikh firing count vector (a value of t_i's) such that M0 the initial state + product of this Parikh vector by incidence matrix gives the reached state. So this one introduces many new variables, and involves some multiplication of variables, but stays a linear integer programming problem.

I separate the steps because since I want UNSAT, any check_sat that returns UNSAT stops the procedure, and the last step in particular is very costly.

I have issues with larger models, where I get prohibitively long answer times or even the dreaded "unknown" answer, particularly when adding state equation (step 3).

*Background*

So besides splitting the problem into incrementally harder segments I've tried setting logic to QF_LRA rather than QF_LIA, and declaring the variables as Real than integers.

This overapproximation is computationally friendly (z3 is fast on these !) but unfortunately for many models the solutions are not integers, nor is there an integer solution.

So I've tried setting Reals, but specifying that each variable is either =0 or >=1, to remove solutions with fractions of firings < 1. This does eliminate spurious solutions, but it "kills" z3 (timeout or unknown) in many cases, the problem is obviously much harder (e.g. harder than with just integers).

*Examples*

I don't have a small example to show, though I can produce some easily. The problem is if I go for QF_LIA it gets prohibitively slow at some number of variables. As a metric, there are many more transitions than places, so adding the state equation really ups the variable count.

[This code](https://github.com/lip6/ITSTools/blob/28fa1c65196b1ba75516ae6af2bc8210671ca079/smt/fr.lip6.move.gal.gal2smt/src/fr/lip6/move/gal/gal2smt/DeadlockTester.java#L235-L278) is generating the examples I'm asking about.

This [general presentation](http://www.lsv.fr/~schwoon/enseignement/verification/ws0910/nets2) slides 5 and 6 express the problem I'm encoding precisely, and slides 7 and 8 develop the results of what "unsat" gives us, if you want more mathematical background.

I'm generating problems from the [Model Checking Contest](https://mcc.lip6.fr), with up to thousands of places (primary variables) and in some cases above a hundred thousand transitions. These are extremum, the middle range is a few thousand places, and maybe 20 thousand transitions that I would really like to deal with.

Reals + the greater than 1 constraint is not a good solution even for some smaller problems. Integers are slow from the get-go.

I could try Reals then iterate into Integers if I get a non integral solution, I have not tried that, though it involves pretty much killing and restarting the solver it might be a decent approach on my benchmark set.

*What I'm looking for*

I'm looking for some settings for Z3 that can better help it deal with the problems I'm feeding it, give it some insight.
I have some a priori idea about what could solve these problems, traditionally they've been fed to ILP solvers. So I'm hoping to trigger a simplex of some sort, but maybe there are conditions preventing z3 from using the "good" solution strategy in some cases.

I've become a decent level SMT/Z3 user, but I've never played with the fine settings of :options, to guide the solver.

Have any of you tried feeding what are basically ILP problems to SMT, and found options settings or particular encodings that help it deploy the right solutions ? thanks.

Comment: I'm encoding linear constraints (the "state equation") I'm not sure what SAT encoding you're thinking about, but for instance this stuff can answer on unbounded Petri nets in some cases, so no direct SAT encoding seems equivalent.

Comment: ok i've linked to a mathematical formulation of the problem from a course on Petri nets if that helps